# how to sort data by current time in sqlite in ios

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to solve the problem
I save data in sqlite.
The date format is

```
NSDateFormatter *df= [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
df.dateFormate = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
DateTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:MyPicker.date]];
```

The value save in Sqlite Table.

I have three button in table currentdate,pastdate,futuredate.

When I press currentdate button, the currentdate values are show in table,

When I press pastdate button, the pastdate values are show in table,

When I press futuredate button,the futuredate values are show in table.

In pastdate is sort data by sqlite Query is

```
NSString *Querysql = [NSString stringWithFormate:@"SELECT *FROM Table_Name where Date > '16-12-2013' order by date DESC"];
```

How to show in current date?

What is the Query for get current date, values  in sqlite table?

Comment: Using "dd-MM-yyyy" will complicate your code too much and prevent you to use many optimizations such as `INDEX`es. Use "yyyy-MM-dd" to store dates in database and format as desired to show in application. Check [SQLite date/time](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Answer (score 0):

Get the current date first

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

// format it
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

// convert it to a string
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

Then use the Query

```
String Querysql = "SELECT *FROM Table_Name where Date = \""+dateString+"\" ";
```